# How to convert timestamp to date in an array created with a for-loop?

Tags: javascript

I created an array with a for-loop which can show me all days in a certain timespan every week or every two weeks, it worked, but now i would like to convert these timestamps to local german time (i used  `.toLocaleDateString("de-DE")`  dd.mm.yyyy).
I am not able to solve the problem above and seek for your help. I tried it, as mentioned, with `.toLocaleDateString("de-DE")` but it was no success.

My Code for both days:

```
function datenSpuckerErsterTag(){

  let bTagEins = Date.parse(document.getElementById("firstDatum").value);

  let bTagzwei = Date.parse(document.getElementById("secondDatum").value);

  let startDatum1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("startDatum").value );

  let endDatum1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("endDatum").value);



  const siebenTage = 86400 * 1000*7;
  const vierzehnTage = 86400 * 1000*14 ;


  if (valueGetter1() == 7) {
    let datenListe = [];

    for (let i = bTagEins; i <= endDatum1; i = i + siebenTage) {

      datenListe.push(i);
      console.log(datenListe);
      document.getElementById("arrOnePrint").innerHTML = datenListe;
    }
  } else if (valueGetter1() == 14){

    let datenListe = [];
    for(let i = bTagEins;i <= endDatum1;i=i + vierzehnTage) {

      datenListe.push (i);
      console.log(datenListe);
      document.getElementById("arrOnePrint").innerHTML = datenListe;
    }
  } else {}
}

function datenSpuckerZweiterTag(){

  let bTagEins = Date.parse(document.getElementById("firstDatum").value);

  let bTagZwei = Date.parse(document.getElementById("secondDatum").value);

  let startDatum1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("startDatum").value );

  let endDatum1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById("endDatum").value);



  const siebenTage = 86400 * 1000*7;
  const vierzehnTage = 86400 * 1000*14 ;


  if (valueGetter2() == 7) {
    let datenListe = [];

    for (let i = bTagZwei; i <= endDatum1; i = i + siebenTage) {

      datenListe.push(i);
      console.log(datenListe);
      document.getElementById("arrTwoPrint").innerHTML = datenListe;
    }
  } else if (valueGetter2() == 14){

    let datenListe = [];
    for(let i = bTagZwei;i <= endDatum1;i=i + vierzehnTage) {

      datenListe.push (i);
      console.log(datenListe);
      document.getElementById("arrTwoPrint").innerHTML = datenListe;
    }
  } else {}
}
```

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate any advice!  <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
const date = new Date();

// ✅ Get a string according to a provided Time zone
console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  }),
); // ️ "9/14/2022, 1:24:19 AM"

console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
    timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  }),
); // ️ "14.9.2022, 10:24:19"

// ✅ Or get a Date object with the specified Time zone
function changeTimeZone(date, timeZone) {
  if (typeof date === 'string') {
    return new Date(
      new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', {
        timeZone,
      }),
    );
  }

  return new Date(
    date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone,
    }),
  );
}

const laDate = changeTimeZone(new Date(), 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(laDate); // ️ "Wed Sep 14 2022 01:24:19"

const berlinDate = changeTimeZone(new Date(), 'Europe/Berlin');
console.log(berlinDate); // ️ "Wed Sep 14 2022 10:24:19"
```

Comment: I've solved the problem myself -  thank you anyways for the help!